# foreach loop doesn't execute

Tags: php, loops, foreach

hi i have a form that takes several answers in checkboxes

```
<p>Select the modules you take:<br />
Module1 <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Module1"/><br />
Module2 <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Module2" /><br />
Module3 <input type="checkbox" name="modules" value="Module3" /><br /></p>
```

now in the response page i have the foreach loop, but it doesn't execute anything

```
foreach ($modules as $selected){
    print "<p>Modules are ".$selected."</p>";
};
```

any help with this? thanks in advance

Comment: Please watch a tutorial how to receive data from a html form. We are not a school here, this might help you to get a start: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: If the check box is unchecked then the form will post nothing

Comment: Your misusing the checbox as well the name should be the value and if checked you will get the name and value as 1 in the post

Answer (score 1):

If you name your checkboxes like this, you get an array (with the brackets [])

```
<input type="checkbox" name="modules[]" value="Module1"/>
```

and of course you need to iterate the correct array:

```
foreach($_POST['modules'] as $selected) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may know,`foreach` loop is used for arrays.
in your php response code, you should make `$modules=$_POST['modules']`.

and the `foreach` loop should look like this:

```
foreach($modules as $selected){ print "<p>Modules are " . $selected . "</p>"; }
```

Check [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) article to get more familiar with `foreach` loops.